# Inheritance in C++ internals

Tags: c++

Can some one explain me how inheritance is implemented in C++ ?

Does the base class gets actually copied to that location or just refers to that location ?

What happens if a function in base class is overridden in derived class ? Does it replace it with the new function or copies it in other location in derived class memory ?

Comment: Are you asking about the layout of instantiated objects?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

first of all you need to understand that C++ is quite different to e.g. Java, because there is no notion of a "Class" retained at runtime. All OO-features are compiled down to things which could also be achieved by plain C or assembler.

Having said this, what acutally happens is that the compiler generates kind-of a `struct`, whenever you *use* your class definition. And when you invoke a "method" on your object, actually the compiler just encodes a call to a *function* which resides somewhere in the generated executable.

Now, if your class inherits from another class, the compiler somehow includes the fields of the baseclass in the *struct* he uses for the derived class. E.g. it *could* place these fields at the front and place the fields corresponding to the derived class after that. Please note: you **must not** make any assumptions regarding the concrete memory layout the C++ compiler uses. If you do so, you're basically on your own and loose any portability.

How is the inheritance implemented? well, it depends!

- if you use a *normal* function, then the compiler will use the concrete type he's figured out and just encode a jump to the right function.
- if you use a *virtual* function, the compiler will generate a vtable and generate code to look up a function pointer from that vtable, depending on the run time type of the object

This distinction is very important in practice. Note, it is *not true* that inheritance is *allways* implemented through a vtable in C++ (this is a common gotcha). Only if you mark a certain member function as `virtual` (or have done so for the same member function in a baseclass), then you'll get a call which is directed at runtime to the right function. Because of this, a `virtual` function call is *much slower* than a non-virtual call (might be several hundered times)

Comment: I agree that normal functions can be used, but if not using virtual, don't you have to cast the object to the concrete type before making the method call?  http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Virtual_function

Comment: A virtual method call can be slower than a non-virtual method call, but from there to *much slower* and *several hundred times* slower I think you are over exaggerating **a lot** (and I know that *over exaggerate* is an improper exaggeration in itself). Without multiple inheritance, a virtual method call will only take an extra level of indirection from a direct method call. While that can slow down things, in particular when that impacts branch prediction in the processor, I would find it hard to consider that to cause a 1:100 performance degradation per-se.

Comment: ... also note that the compiler does not need to use the virtual dispatch mechanism it it can resolve at compile time the actual type of the object --as would be required for non-virtual methods.

Comment: @SB: casting is not the complete solution. If at the place of call there is a reference to a base, manually downcasting to the concrete type may not be enough, as the compiler may not be able to know that the concrete object is of that type and not some further derived type, so it would still use the dynamic dispatch mechanism, you would also need to disable the virtual dispatch by selecting the final overrider manually: `void f( base & b ) { static_cast<derived&>(b).derived::foo() }`. Note the cast would also be required for non-virtual method call, the `.derived::` makes the difference.

Comment: @dribeas agreed that the difference isn't so large on average. But I want to stress the fact *that* there is a difference, which seems to be difficult to grasp for developers e.g. grown up e.g. with java or C#.

Comment: ah and to complete the picture, we should mention the possibility of *inlining*: If the compiler has a full *definition* of the member function to be called available at the call site, then he might decide not to do any function call and rather copy the function code in place and adjust it accordingly. As each function call requires the compiler to generate some "boilerplate" code for argument passing and return value etc, for very short functions this can give an dramatic performance boost. (but as with any optimisation, your milage may vary,you'd need to measure in each practical situation)

Comment: ...obviously only a statically dispatched function call can be inlined

Comment: @Ichthyo: But even calls to virtual functions can sometimes be dispatched statically.

Answer (score 2):

Inheritance in C++ is often accomplished via the [vtable](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Virtual_method_table).  The linked Wikipedia article is a good starting point for your questions.  If I went into more detail in this answer, it would essentially be a regurgitation of it.

Comment: @sb a vtable is not strictly required for inheritance. See the answer of Ichthyo.

Comment: @SB there is no need for vtable for inheritence. Its required for dynamic binding right ?

Comment: for dynamic binding, yes. In case a vtable gets used for a given member function, the "iheritance" handling is done at initialisation of the vtable, by placing the pointer to the right function into the vtable. Typically, a C++ compiler generates a (hidden) function for each distinct type, which, when called, emits and configures the vtable for this type. (All of this can be more involved when multiple inheritance comes into play, but the principle remains the same)

Comment: @Ichthyo: Compilers will not usually update pointers *at initialization* of the vtable. In most cases, given a class `base` with at least a virtual method and a derived class `derived` (for simplicity consider that `derived` overrides, but does not add more virtual methods), the compiler will emit two different fixed vtable's, one for `base` and one for `derived`. During object initialization, after the `base` constructor has completed and before entering the rest of the derived initialization list, the virtual table pointer is updated --not the pointers in the vtable, but a pointer to vtable.

Comment: another aspect worth mentioning is that due to this initial setup of the vtable(s), creating *lots* of different types with virtual functions can significantly bloat your executable. (you can get lots of different types by careless use of templates)